# RxJava-Computation-Expressions vs. conditional expression

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, rx-java

There is [RxJava-Computation-Expressions](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaComputationExpressions) extension for RxJava. It provides operators like `ifThen` and others. However, the advantages of using it are not obvious. Because standard if-else block can be used or ternary operator, which are way readable and usual. I checked different functional languages and didn't find similar construction. All of them are using standard if-else operator.

Moreover, such extension is available not for all Rx languages and available only for RxJava 1.x.

The question is: what is the purpose of using `ifThen` operator from RxJava? Which advantages could it give comparing to standard if-else or ternary operator?

Answer (score 0):

They allow taking a branch at subscription time and not when the sequence is assembled. It can mean that different subscribers will get different branches.

[Further reading](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#computational-expressions).